# Is StorageReference.getDownloadUrl() declared inside uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

As referenced in firebase doc, I have to call getDownloadUrl() on the StorageReference after uploading file. So the task should be declared inside addOnSuccessListener?

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("your_REF");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }

            // Continue with the task to get the download URL
            return ref.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            } else {
                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()` can be called before the upload has finished, or even has been started. Of course the file at the download URL won't be available until the upload has been completed, so you'll want a flagging mechanism for that in completion listener for the upload task.